# Rename a global array TCL

Tags: arrays, tcl, global

I have a global array that I need to be able to rename and can't seem to get this right.

```
array set DataReturn {
    red   1
    green 5
    blue  4
    white 9
}

proc _RenameArray {Arr NewArrName} {
    global $NewArrName
    upvar #0 $Arr $NewArrName
    array unset $Arr
}

_RenameArray DataReturn TheArr
```

I know that there is a lot that I am missing here. any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @DonalF would you be able to assist on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends. Tcl variables can't be renamed, not truly, but they can effectively have multiple names. You make them with `upvar`. In particular, `upvar 0` will give another name to a variable in the current scope.

```
upvar 0 DataReturn TheArr
```

Under the covers, this makes `TheArr` a *linked* variable; it's real contents are a pointer to the other variable (which can be an array, of course) but any action on the linked variable is converted into an action on the underlying variable (except for changing the link to point to something else). The only way in which this isn't a rename is that the original variable still exists and can't be removed.

If you can't do that, your only option is to copy the variable to another variable and `unset` the originating one. This is trivial for simple variables:

```
set TheNew $TheOld
unset TheOld
```

and only slightly more complicated for arrays:

```
array set TheNew [array get TheOld]
unset TheOld
```

However, this does not preserve variables that link into the array, or any traces that are set. Copy-remove isn't the same as rename.

---

Turning things into procedures is a little more complex, as variable name resolution is sensitive to the context in which it is performed. As such, some care with `upvar` and `uplevel` is potentially required. I'll not talk through these options; the core of the operation is what I talk about above, but they're done in a context-sensitive way (`"#0"` is in quotes because of the syntax highlighting here):

```
proc RenameGlobalVariable {OldName NewName} {
    uplevel "#0" [list upvar 0 $OldName $NewName]
}
```

```
proc RenameGlobalSimpleVariable {OldName NewName} {
    upvar "#0" $OldName old $NewName new
    set new $old
    unset old
}
```

```
proc RenameGlobalArray {OldName NewName} {
    upvar "#0" OldName old $NewName new
    array set new [array get old]
    unset old
}
```

Comment: It is of course easy to copy traces from one variable to another (modulo some edge conditions). To copy the traces set on `foo` to `bar`, just use `foreach ti [trace info variable foo] {trace add variable bar {*}$ti}`.

Comment: @Donal Thanks I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

It can be simplified:

```
proc _RenameArray {Arr NewArrName} {
  upvar $Arr Temp
  global $NewArrName
  array set $NewArrName [array get Temp]
  uplevel #0 array unset Temp
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the code review. I am always looking to optimize my code! I am sure taking the `foreach` out will speed things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head on my desk for awhile I got it.

```
proc _RenameArray {Arr NewArrName} {
    global [subst $NewArrName];
    upvar #0 $Arr Temp;
    foreach {Key Value} [array get Temp] {
        set [subst $NewArrName]($Key) $Value
    }
    uplevel #0 array unset $Arr
}
```

Anyone knows a better way to do this I am all ears!